# Using a file creation/change trigger in IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, .net-6.0

I'm creating client apps for my central system that need to process files and send them over an API.
A 3rd party app will generate files and my client has to pick them up and read them. The client will be configured to monitor a specific folder and only check specific extensions.

For the desktop clients, I can just use a FileSystemWatcher on the folder, but I have no idea how to implement a similar trigger on IOS.

One of the 3rd party apps I need to support is an IOS app, and I rather not bother the user every time a file needs to be processed. My app should run silently in the background, so the user can focus on the 3rd party app. The user still starts my app and configures the folder to watch off course.

Any idea how to implement such a trigger?

Comment: where are these files going to be located that 2 different iOS apps can both access them?

Comment: The 3rd party app uses a standard iOS share dialog, with an option to store it in the Files app to place it in a folder on the device. My app is to keep an eye on that folder and do it's job when a new one arrives.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+monitor+changes+in+shared+folders+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason all those results are in native IOS, I'm using .NET, so Xamarin

Comment: Xamarin uses the same underlying iOS APIs.  If you find the right API that does what you want and need help translating the code into C#, you can ask for help with that.  But for this specific question, understanding what APIs are offered to monitor the iOS file system is the first step.